# C# - Trying to convert Dictionary to JSON

Tags: c#, json

Here is my code:

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string header;
    public Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public int connectionId;
}

JsonData SendData = new JsonData();
SendData.header = "01";
SendData.data.Add("text", "What is Lorem Ipsum?Lorem ");
SendData.data.Add("accId", "123");
SendData.connectionId = 12;

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(SendData);
```

Everything is fine but somehow the key `data` in the converted JSON string does not appear at all.

The `string json` looks like this:

```
{"header":"01","connectionId":12}
```

instead of:

```
{"header":"01","data":{"text":"What is Lorem Ipsum?Lorem ","accId":"123"},"connectionId":12}
```

Where is my mistake ?
Why i can not receive result like this ?

Comment: Want to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to get the right json. Given you have it referenced on your project use the namespace:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

And use the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` static method:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SendData);
```

Comment: Is Newtonsoft.Json available for IOS? I heard it had issues.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html.

> Note that while it is possible to pass primitive types to this method,
>   the results may not be what you expect; instead of serializing them
>   directly, the method will attempt to serialize their public instance
>   fields, producing an empty object as a result. Similarly, passing an
>   array to this method will not produce a JSON array containing each
>   element, but an object containing the public fields of the array
>   object itself (of which there are none). **To serialize the actual**
>   **content of an array or primitive type, it is necessary to wrap it in a**
>   **class or struct**.

Try exposing the contents of data in a property, like the following.

```
    public string dataOutput
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(",", data.Select(x => string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", x.Key, x.Value)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question... The OP is serializing a class (`SendData `) already but one of its public fields is not being serialized despite the fact the other two are. This seems to be more addressing things like `int foo = 1; JsonUtility.ToJson(foo);` which is a different situation.

Comment: @Chris My assumption (not being familiar with Unity) is that it's treating the dictionary as an array, which would explain why it's not serializing it. Since it seems to be serializing primitive type properties, the next logical step would be to see if it's a problem with the data (which my answer would provide).

Comment: You may be half right. Dictionaries do have the same thing as Arrays in that neither of them have any public fields. The bolded line in the quote though suggests that arrays in a class or struct will serialise correctly so by the same logic you'd expect dictionaries to serialize properly if wrapped in a class...

Comment: @Chris Sure, but the best way to prove whether or not that's the issue would be to do as I suggested, and expose the data they wish to show via a property and see if it appears. If it does, perfect, the answer must be at least related to the bolded line. If not, then there's an underlying issue with the dictionary.